# How to place files to Photoshop without scaling?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, resize, ppi

Is there a way to place files in Photoshop without scaling (true pixel of image)? They automatically resize to fit screen when I drag into PSD file! For example, when place a 48x48px to 480x480px PSD, it's scaled to 480x480.

My system info: Photoshop CS5, Windows 7.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce this exact effect. And even the setting "Resize Image During Place" seems to only affect images larger than the canvas.

So my best guess is that the both files need the same resolution. Because pasting a 48x48px (72dpi) image and a 48x48px (144dpi) on a 480x480px (72dpi) canvas have different results.

[image]

Comment: I try out your solution, but no luck, they're still resized without my permission:D.

Comment: I guess what I want you to do is compare the resolution of the files.

Comment: Yes, you are right, two different dpi give us two results, it's OK now! Thank a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing the new image you can open the file and copy/paste or drag/drop from one document to the other.