# What is the proper sizing/image/resolution or whatever for shooting artwork for submission?

Tags: resolution, dpi, ppi, print-production, image-editing

I create colored pencil art and I'm very confused about the whole thing of resolution: A professional print provider is doing the photo shoot of my artwork, and I was just handed an image that is 72 dpi, but the picture is very large. I thought it should be 300 dpi so I could save it into the various sizes I need for mags or printing or submission for shows.  What is the correct way to do this? When I shoot my art myself just for my own use I resize the images to 72 dpi and they then look quite small, the right size for posting on my blog but the 72 dpi image he sent me as mentioned was very large at 72 dpi.  Some advice here please and thank you.  I am new at this and the question was answered but I did not understand a word of it.  Could someone please explain this process in layman's terms please?

Comment: If it's a pixel image, the resolution isn't as important as the *actual number of pixels* you have. A [large, low res image file is basically a small high res image, just described differently](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/whats-the-difference-between-72ppi-and-300ppi). A 3,000 pixel image that thinks it is 42 inches of 72 pixels per inch is essentially the same thing as a 3,000 pixel image that thinks it is 10 inches of 300 pixels per inch.

Comment: Please vote for reopening. The question was wrongly  marked as duplicate.

Comment: @TehMacDawg if you don't feel the linked answer answers this question, please edit the linked answer with additional information to answer this. We're trying to redirect all 'what resolution' questions there as we get so many of them here.

Comment: @TehMacDawg I edited that other answer to hopefully address the particularities of this question. Let me know what you think.