# Problems in Saving as pdf - image resolution decreases and text resolution remains same

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, pdf

i have been facing this problem many times. When ever i save any high resolution image in PDF format, the pictures in the image gets pixelated and the text or any shape remains unpixelated. But whan i view the same image as .jpeg it looks perfect with all the details. The image is fitting to screen of PDF only at 500%, but when i am putting it to 100%, it is coming as small image(image attached). I have attached some image to explain my situation. Please let me know if there is any format of saving files as PDF to get the best output. Or if someone can suggest the best settings to save in PDF.

**This is the PDF output -** 
[image]

**This is the JPEG output -** 
[image]

**These are the settings i used to save as PDF -**

[image]

[image]

**This is Photoshop setting of the image -**

[image]

**This is how the Image looks in PDF at 100% -**

[image]

Comment: It's a 5x7 **centimeter** image. It should look small in a PDF. Photoshop does not use the PPI setting for display. But PDFs do. PDFs are assumed for print, therefore the width, height, and resolution all factor into the final size. Photoshop merely uses the pixel width and height for display.

Comment: ok...thanks a lot.....that was helpful :) So is it because the resolution was more, the cm was less? I tried the dimension 1458*1041px with a resolution of 300 - it was showing 4.8*3.4cm......and i tried the same dimension of 1458*1041px with a resolution of 72 - it was showing 20.2*40.4cm. This is something new for me. Anyways thanks Scott for the info - it will solve my problem. :)

Comment: @scott you should add that as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

On screen, it's the pixel width and pixel height which are used.

In print, the width and height are greatly effected by the overall ppi of the image. Photoshop does not use PPI for on screen display. It uses the pixel with and height. However, when you print the PPI is then factored in.

PDF files are assumed to be for printing. They generally use the width, height, and ppi of any image to determine its overall size.

These previous questions regarding resolution, PPI and DPI may be helpful:

- [What's the difference between 72ppi and 300ppi?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/18837/whats-the-difference-between-72ppi-and-300ppi)
- [Is it mandatory to keep images at 72DPI for web design?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13777/is-it-mandatory-to-keep-72-dpi-for-web-design-what-if-i-create-in-200dpi)

Answer (score 0):

Take a good look at your resolution unit in the “Image Size” window. It's “pixels/cm”. Yet, in your PDF output setting you have “downsample image to 300 pixels/inch when it's bigger than 450 pixels/inch”. 300 pixels/cm is equivalent to 762 pixels/inch (pixels/inch = 2.54 * pixels/cm). So your image (762 PPI) is downsampled to 300 PPI. Voilà! Recipe for a problem :}